# Hide partition with VHD file during specialize or OOBE pass

Tags: windows-7, vhd

I am creating a system based on VHD. The partition is like this:

+----------+-----------+
| VHD file | User Data |
+----------+-----------+
　　|
+------------+
|   SYSTEM   |
+------------+

The system volume has a default drive letter C.
Windows 7 automatically assign letter D for "VHD file" volume and E for "User Data"
The "VHD file" volume also contains bootmgr and page file.

My purpose is to hide "VHD file" volume so that no page file will be located in it and user cannot see vhd file and boot directory in it.

Windows 7 doesn't allow to remove letter after OOBE because the page file is in it. (Thus, we have to relocate page file, restart, and remove letter).

So my guess is do it during OOBE or specialize pass.

The result should be like "SYSTEM RESERVED" 100MB partition -- no drive letter, no page file, but with key files in it.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I made it.

As the first pass is specialize, I let it change drive letters in registry by `REG` command. But remove a drive letter by registry is hard to code, and use of `DISKPART` requires a reboot, so I let it happen in oobe mode.

Here is what I code: (If you have some improvement please notify me :)

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

if "%1"=="specialize" goto specialize
if "%1"=="oobe" (goto oobe) else (goto end)


:specialize
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices"

REM Delete Drive D:
set VALUE_NAME=\DosDevices\D:
reg delete %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% /f

REM Get vaules of Drive E:
set VALUE_NAME=\DosDevices\E:
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)
if not defined ValueName goto end

REM Create Drive D with value of Drive E
set VALUE_NAME=\DosDevices\D:
reg add %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% /t %ValueType% /d %ValueValue% /f
REM Delete Drive E:
set VALUE_NAME=\DosDevices\E:
reg delete %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% /f
REM Set Page File
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management"
set VALUE_NAME=PagingFiles
set ValueType=REG_MULTI_SZ
set ValueValue="D:\pagefile.sys 0 0"
reg add %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% /t %ValueType% /d %ValueValue% /f
REM END
goto end

:oobe
REM Delete Drive E:
(echo select volume e & echo remove letter=e) | diskpart

:end
```

Comment: Well, I find RunSyncronous allows me to reboot when phase one complete. So It is possible to complete the two steps in specialize pass. BTW, command in OOBE only works during logon, so the specialize solution is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Use MDT 2012, this should be able to be done with a task sequence.

Sounds like you may be making this more complicated than it needs to be. MDT is the system Microsoft released back with Vista and Windows 7 to make Operating System Deployment (OSD) much simpler.

[image]
TEST Task Sequence

[image]
Deploy to VHD is an optional Task Sequence Step

[image]
Note that the image can be pushed to whatever drive you want.

Comment: More information would make this a more useful answer.  Can you update?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this way doesn't work for me. This task only specifies the drive letter for the OS. In VHD boot mode, bcd loads necessary drivers and mount vhd file automatically. Because the system will be installed in a virtual partition,  the physical partition that holds vhd files will be assigned a drive letter during OOBE or specialized pass. In diskmgmt.msc, you can see two disks: 1) physical disk, 2) virtual disk mounted from vhd. I am looking for a way to prevent the physcial partition that holds vhd files from being mounted.